# AngularJS controller not changing the angular variable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am learning angularjs so if it may be a silly mistake please help.
I was writing this simple angular application where I am checking the two passwords strings in ng-controller and displaying a short message about if they match or not.
Here is the complete short program image:[code image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtkFM.png)

It seems to me to be correct but I must be doing something wrong. Please point out.

Comment: why don't you put this code in a plunker or write it in your question instead of linking an image?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your code to check if the values are the same is only run at load time. What you need to do it run it when the values change:

```
<div ng-app-"myApp" ng-controller="MainCntrl">
    Password:
    <input type="password" ng-model="pass" ng-change="change()" /><br />
    Confrom password:
    <input type="password" ng-model="passConf" ng-change="change()" /><br />

    <p>{{check}}</p>
</div>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller("MainCntrl", function($scope){
    $scope.change = function(){
        if (angular.equals($scope.pass, $scope.passConf)){
            $scope.check = "Right"; 
        }else{
            $scope.check = "Wrong";
        }
    }
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ger97ote/

Comment: well I tried it. Still no. I see in "ng-change" you are calling check() method when we have none defined?

Comment: @HarshvardhanSolanki if this answer solved your problem you should accept it.

Comment: @ryanyuyu Yes thank you I did Chris was very helpful and I vote for it :)

Comment: I think I deserve an up vote just for retyping everything in the attached picture! :)